# Do I need a DAC if I already have good audio in my motherboard?

Tags: headphones

Motherboard : [ASUS Maximus VII Ranger](https://www.asus.com/au/ROG_ROG/MAXIMUS_VII_RANGER/specifications/)

> Audio ROG SupremeFX 8-Channel High Definition Audio CODEC
>
> - Supports : Jack-detection, Multi-streaming, Front Panel Jack-retasking
> - SupremeFX Shielding Technology
> - ELNA® premium audio capacitors Audio Feature :
> - DTS Connect
> - Optical S/PDIF out port(s) at back panel
> - Sonic SoundStage
> - Sonic SenseAmp
> - Sonic Studio
> - Sonic Radar II

---

I don't know how to assess sound cards, but since the Z97 series motherboards are the newest, and the ASUS Maximus range is kind of top of the line, I assumed that in terms of built-in motherboard audio, this would be top of the line as well.

However, I'm considering upping my headphone game and planning to buy a high-end one that needs an amp. I see amps sold as DAC/amps, or just amps, and I see other people buying separate DACs and amps.

Now, I was wondering if buying a DAC would make much of a difference if my motherboard audio is already good.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the place for such a question.  This MIGHT be on topic on MusicFans SE, and maybe Computer Science..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't have anything to do with practice or theory of music, rather the listening aspect.

Comment: Is it not under **usage of specific music software or hardware** based in the [help center](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I don't think so.   This isn't about using the DAC.

Comment: Well, if that is so, I'll wait and see if it will garner enough close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear... you're only looking for audio *output*, correct? You aren't planning to do any recording? I ask, because usually, when I see people asking about external soundcards, it's going the other way -- they're looking at recording, and need a better ADC (Analog to Digital Converter).

I would expect built-in soundcards to be more oriented towards an audio consumer (rather than an audio producer) since it's way more common for folks to listen to audio than record it. So I would probably expect a high-end card to be "good enough" for output. Granted, I've never claimed to have the most discerning ear.

What I would do is start off with the headphones (the speakers you use will have way more influence on the resulting sound anyway) and then, if you're still unsatisfied with the resulting sound, you *might* consider a DAC. But I'm personally skeptical that it would make that much of a difference. I mean... how sensitive are your ears to small changes?

In retrospect, I suppose this question could potentially be seen as too opinion based for this site.